# Getting a column range by the headers input

Tags: excel, vba

I built a function `getHeadersRange` that receives a column name (Header from the first row) and **brings back the range of the specific column** from the 2nd cell to the last.

I was wondering if is there any **faster/more efficient way** to receive the required range.

The function uses another function - `Col_Letter`.

anyone can think of a better solution?

Thanks!

```
Function getHeadersRange(colName As String) As Range

   Dim header_address As Range
   Dim Rng_header As Range

   Dim numOfDataRows As Long

   numOfDataRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

   Set header_address = Cells.Find(what:=colName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
   LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

   If header_address Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox (colName + " header was Not found")
   Else

        Set Rng_header = Range(Col_Letter(header_address.Column) & 2 & ":" & 
         Col_Letter(header_address.Column) & numOfDataRows)
    
   End If

   Set getHeadersRange = Rng_header

End Function
```

The sub function in use:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String

   Dim vArr
   vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
   Col_Letter = vArr(0)

End Function
```

**Clarification** - I do not know how many rows and columns there will be in the worksheet. I even don't know what is the worksheet name or where the column I'm looking for is. The only thing I do know is that If the column does exist I want to save the range of the cells starting from the second cell until the last row.

Comment: What do you want doing with the range returned by the above function code? Do you want copying it somewhere? If yes, do you need to copy the range format, too? I am asking that, in order to show you a globally faster way, using/returning an array... Then, don't you know the row where the headers should be? Since your function builds a range starting from the second row, the assumption that the headers are in the first row is correct?

Comment: I'm using the function for different things such as editing the cell values, copying them, coloring the cells and etc @FaneDuru

Comment: I don't know where in the excel sheet the column will appear and if so, what I do know is that if it founds, I want to apply some actions on it.

Comment: If so, why do you build the range starting from the second row? Do you want including the header in the range...?

Comment: yes, I need the range to start from the second row. (Header not needed)

Comment: You could just use `cells` `range(cells(2,10),cells(100,10))` for example will select column 10, rows 2 to 100?

Comment: I am afraid that you did not get me. But I wish you success!

Comment: or header_address.resize.... could be an option too?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Not sure I got you

Comment: Clarification -  I  do not know how many rows and columns there will be in the worksheet. 
I even don't know what is the worksheet name or where the column I'm looking for is. 
The only thing I do know is that If the column does exist I want to save the range of the cells starting from the second cell until the last row.

Comment: use `range(cells(firstrow,colnumber),cells(lastrow,colnumber))` or `header_address.resize(rowcount,1)`  Look at the help for both, that will help you.  Also, `& 2 & ":" ` will cause an error i think, should be ` & "2:" &